# Past tense substitute for "current" or "actual"

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense

How **writing in the past** could I refer to the ***current*** wife of a man who had been married twice?

Could I simply use ***current***, because it's understandable that I am not referring to the date of the writer but the date of the character...?

Should I use **"latter"**, the antonym for **"former"**, instead?

> E.g. Jim had been married twice. His former wife was a school teacher,
>   and the latter was a nurse.

Does it sound right?

Comment: Why do you think that "current" is incorrect? Is Jim **still** married to the nurse?

Comment: Because I am referring to the past, therefore I have no knowledge as of the present time, the time I am writing, if he is still married to her or not.

Comment: With regard to your title, it's rare for "actual" to mean "current".  "Actual" usually means "real", "true", "authentic".

Comment: @rjpond, indeed. I met however phrases where it had been used as "current". Nevertheless, that is only a matter of preference, old-style vs modern style, whether my confusion is regarding the meaning of its substitute, or as you prefer, the substitute for "current" in past tense speaking.

Comment: No... if someone said "actual wife", I'd assume that they were lying about who they were married to ... "*I'm Nurse... Jim's **actual** wife... I don't know who this impostor is.*"

Comment: I found in some dictionaries examples where "actual" was said to mean "current", but they were all in specialised or semi-specialised financial contexts, and in every case "actual" could equally well be understood as meaning "real" (since it was being contrasted with "estimated", "projected", "future" - and therefore inherently uncertain -, etc).

Comment: @QOTSA as rjpond remarks, "actual" means "real", but it is a false friend in a couple of languages. For example in German, the near-homophone "aktuell" (sounds like "actual") means "current", same in French with the word "actuel(le)".

Answer (score 19):

You have a couple of issues.

You're calling the nurse a "current" wife when you don't really know if that's the case.

Someone who is "currently" a spouse to someone means that they are *still* married. In that case, you wouldn't write the sentence in the past tense at all:

> Jim has been married twice. His former wife was a school teacher and his *current* one is/was a nurse.

When you say "had been" it implies that he is not currently married at all. The more common choice here, since there is no "current" spouse, is to use numbers:

> Jim had been married twice. His first wife was a school teacher and his second was a nurse.

Comment: Actually, by using past perfect I meant to point out that I have not knowledge of his present marital status. Thereby, I wanted to use **"current"** as *present tense* mixed within *past tense* speaking/writing. I assume I did it wrong. Some do it, but they know how to, and when to, for sounding intelligible. Thanks for your answer, @Catija!

Comment: You can't really do that... if you really want to "point out" that you have no knowledge of his current status, you have to say so... "*but I'm not sure if they're still married*.".

Comment: The use of the past perfect doesn't imply that he is no longer married at the time of the speaking.   He might have gotten married three more times since then, and be married to his fifth wife now.  As of the time referenced in the past, he had had two wives.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Neither case allows for the use of "current" in reference to the second wife, which is my primary point.

Comment: @Catija: **I have been married twice** does not necessarily imply that my second marriage is over, even if people might tend to infer that I'm twice divorced (or  a widower, or a combination).

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo upvote for correct use of imply and infer

Answer (score 17):

Catija has done a good job answering your question; however, I feel like someone should elaborate on how you aren't using *former* and *latter* in the standard way:

> Jim had been married twice. His former wife was a school teacher, and the latter was a nurse.

Normally, *former* and *latter* refers to two previously-named items. You imply two previous spouses when you say "twice," but they aren't listed or named. Catija fixed that by changing *latter* to *current*, but it might be worth pointing out how the sentences could be restructured such that you could use *former* and *latter*.

For example, you could say something like this:

> Jim has two ex-wives, Jane and Linda. The former was a schoolteacher and the latter is a nurse.

In that example, *former* refers to the first of two in a list (Jane), while *latter* refers to the second (Linda).

These don't always need to refer to people; I could say something like:

> I have two hobbies, skydiving and stamp collecting. The former is much more dangerous than the latter.

But I wouldn't (or shouldn't) say:

> I have two hobbies; the former is much more dangerous than the latter.

because the hobbies haven't been explicitly named, so there is nothing for *former* and *latter* to point back to.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that "latter" is the antonym for a *different* usage of "former" than what the OP wants.

Comment: -1 because "former" and "latter" work perfectly fine for chronology; they are not limited to order of appearance in a list.  In fact, making a list creates ambiguity, because the reader then is not clear whether the listing order matches chronological order.

Comment: @BenV - Two points: (1) I was careful to avoid saying that the OP's usage was "wrong," "incorrect," or "ungrammatical," instead pointing out that is was not "the standard way" the terms are "normally" used. (2) As for that added ambiguity, it's only an issue if it's important to what the speaker is trying to say. I don't claim my sentence about Jane and Linda is an equivalent to, or conveys the same information as, the original. Rather, it was just a convenient way to show the learner how we see _former_ and _latter_ used most often.

Answer (score 11):

> We interviewed him in the 1990s. His first wife was a high school teacher and his *[then current](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22then%20current%20wife%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en)* wife was the mayor  of San Antonio.

The word **then** can be used adverbially to modify (temporally situate) adjective **current**:    "*at-that-time* current".

You can also say "his wife at the time", as other answers have said.

Comment: I upvoted for "then current", but I have to point out that it only works in a situation different from the OP's: The situation where the time meant by "then" is specified.

Comment: It's not a relevant difference, @Beanluc, since the past perfect in OP's example does much the same thing.  *Jim **had been married** twice*.

Comment: I think "then-current" fits the description of what the OP is asking, but "former" fits better into the example they provided. If you say "While he was going to college, Jim's then-current wife was a school teacher. His current wife is a nurse", that makes more sense than "former". For the example of "Jim had been married twice before. His former wife was a school teacher, his latter wife was a nurse, but he is once again single", "former" works better since we don't have a frame of reference for "then-current".

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it actually explained what it's saying rather than simply being an example of use.

Comment: @Catija: What's to explain?  The conventional way to refer to something being current as of a particular time in the past is to refer to it as the **then current {something}**.  I think you're getting bogged down in the particulars of OP's example, missing the forest for the trees.

Comment: It's obvious to you, sure... and me... but you're on a site for people who aren't native speakers of English and who need help understanding a concept. This is not an answer.

Comment: @Catija: Still, there's nothing to **explain** except perhaps the use of **then** as a modifier. I will add that.

Comment: Do you need “current” after “then”? Surely “his then wife” is a sufficient and complete descriptor? It does imply that she is no longer his wife, but “then current” doesn’t solve that problem

Comment: I think the bit missing from this answer is that "then current" at least very strongly implies that conditions have changed (i.e. that his "then current" wife is not his wife *now*, for whatever reason). It doesn't work nearly as well if we don't know the subject's present marital status. As an aside, "then" is also sometimes used alone with this same meaning, almost always with relationships, as in "she divorced her **then husband** when she found him in bed with his **then mistress**, whom he subsequently married" (sometimes hyphenated, *then-wife* etc.).

Comment: @1006a: Again, I think this is paying too much attention to non-essential aspects of the question.  The OP, as I understand the question, wants to refer to something that was *current as of a particular time in the past*. There is nothing in the question that should make us be concerned about the present. That said, I could say "My then current wife, to whom I am still happily married.*

Comment: You're right, the OP needs to edit some relevant comments into the actual question, specifically "Because I am referring to the past, therefore I have no knowledge as of the present time, the time I am writing, if he is still married to her or not." If I heard "my then current wife" without any qualifying statement, I would generally assume she was no longer your wife, which (from comments) doesn't appear to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @verbose:  "My then wife" is also possible, but it would be misguided to think that *natural* language is concerned with rigorous notions of sufficiency and completeness.

Comment: Per Google Ngram (usual caveats apply), ["his then wife" is more common in writing than "his then current wife"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=his+then+wife%2Chis+then+current+wife&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chis%20then%20wife%3B%2Cc0) (the latter doesn't even register). It strikes me as a rather formal/archaic usage, more typical in legalese and history tomes than casual speech, but by no means "unnatural".

Comment: @1006a: Please click on the hyperlink I provided in my answer.  Your ngram search is flawed.

Comment: I didn't say "then current wife" is unheard of, just less common in print than "then wife". Your Google Books search peters out at 12 pages, with fully-viewable examples numbering just 41. A similar search for "his then wife" has [more than sixty pages of results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22his+then+wife%22&lr=lang_en&safe=active&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=8Lg6WoqAKsrqjwSbtqawAw&start=620&sa=N&biw=1866&bih=966&dpr=0.9), and more than 200 actually-viewable results, even though it is more restrictive (omitting phrases like "Smith's then wife").

Comment: @1006a:   The phrase **then current {something}** is widely used. It is not a rarity or oddity by any means. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22then%20current%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1749,cd_max:1946&lr=lang_en    (contains some unrelated uses but the point is that it is a phrase of long-standing)

Comment: You're setting up a straw-man. I have no beef with the usage "then current". I just said that, for romantic relationships, the phrase "then X" as in *then wife* or *then husband* or *then paramour* etc. is more common in print. That's not a sweeping denunciation of your suggestion, just (I thought) a useful footnote.

Comment: @1006a:  My answer is about how to refer to *anything* which was current at some time in the past. **then current {whatever}**.  It just happens to use "wife" as the {whatever}

Answer (score 6):

Generally to refer to 'current' in the past you could use **"at the time"**. This also makes clear whether Jim is/was still married.
Compare

> Jim had been married twice. His wife **at the time** was a nurse, while his former wife had been a school teacher.

with

> Jim had been married twice. His former wife was a school teacher, the latter was a nurse, but he was now single again.

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep things simple :

> Jim had been married twice.  First to a schoolteacher then to a nurse.